# WAMP external connectivity problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ssl, remote-access

I'm setting up a WAMP server with SSL on XP SP2.

-Default port 80 && 443 are NOT forwarded.

The server's admin forwarded ports 1000-1010 && 8080.

When I change httpd config file to listen to port 8080 for regular HTTP && SSL on 1001

8080 - Brings me to a routers/gateway login screen.
1001 - "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length"

This is my first time setting up a HTTP/S server.

Localhost works perfectly. I'm not setting up Virtualhosts because I'm NOT wanting to connect to this via DNS.

Comment: WAMP should be used for development only. You're asking to get hacked if you expose it to the internet (which is what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with  ErikA. You should never put a WAMP server in the wild. 
Its fine to run on the Intra-net. Fine for business applications. Fine for development work. But we live in a world where this is a small challenge to crackers.